# HttpGet Attribute not usable when including the System.Web.Mvc libraries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a Web API which differentiates between `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` request types. I just added the `System.Web.Mvc` and `System.Web.Mvc.Ajax` namespaces to the project, and my ability to define `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` disappears. It can't find the attributes anymore.

What's goin' on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you including both the System.Web.Http and System.Web.Mvc namespaces in the same file?

I can't think of a lot of good reasons why you would want to do that, but if you are, then you need to add the full namespace. See below for an example. Since both the Mvc and Http namespaces have a HttpGet and HttpPost, you need to specify which one to use.

[image: HttpGet for Http and Mvc]

Comment: Though I can't test it 'cause it's at work and I'm not, I suspect this is the answer I'm looking for. As to why I included both? Well, the `System.Web.Http` is included in a new Web API file by default -- so I left that in. I wanted `JsonResult` type, though, which lives in `System.Web.Mvc` -- thus the inclusion of that. Feel free to offer some pointers here, sounds like I'm doing something wrong :)

Comment: I think I've solved my own problem. I didn't realize that it naturally responds in JSON. I was seeing XML when I requested the particular url from chrome, but it looks like if I call it without browser-included headers (e.g. using javascript) I will get JSON. Guess that the `System.Web.Mvc` is not what I want.

Comment: I think this article (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) is what you are looking for. If you want to specify that you want xml or json, then you need to add a content-type to your header. I would recommend fiddler (https://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for testing as it allows you to make requests and change headers fairly easily.